# SQL Server how to link a column name to an external variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I made a code in SQL that separates an item from each record of a column without repeating, and it is working correctly, follow the code below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Tab_Dados_Escolha.Nome_Produto FROM Tab_Dados_Escolha
```

However I would like to replace the name of the column where this routine will be done with an external variable, so I could use this same code for the other columns without having to rewrite another code and I am not able to do it so far, can someone help me?

Comment: You would have to use dynamic SQL -- that is, constructing the query as a string and then executing it.  This is not recommended, because it opens the code to SQL injection attacks and unexpected syntax errors.

Comment: You can't use a variable to replace a literal, you would have to use Dynamic SQL and ***safely*** inject the value into the statement. Also, for something like this, you are better off using `DISTINCT` rather than a `GROUP BY`. `GROUP BY` is *meant* to be used when performing some form of aggregation.

Comment: You can't. Tables and columns are equivalent to types and fields in a strongly typed functional language. They schema has to be known when a query is parsed by the query engine. The SQL query is the *language* that gets compiled into an execution plan, the same way C# or F# code is compiled into an executable. Query parameters are the same as a program's arguments. They can't affect the compiled program, they're data that's used by it

Comment: I suspect this is really an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What is the problem you are *really* trying to solve here?

Comment: Indeed, that query is essentially a `DISTINCT`. Why use a `GROUP BY` then? What repetition are you trying to avoid? Are you trying to analyze the contents of a table, the way Pandas or .NET DataFrame do? Those libraries don't calculate measures individually, because that would require reading the data multiple times. Executing a DISTINCT for each column means you scan the entire table multiple times. These libraries calculate multiple measures at the same time while scanning the data row by row

Comment: Thanks so much for help, the code was updated

Comment: @VitorMarquesLourenço what are you trying to do though? Calculate the distinct values for all rows in a table? The query  `SELECT DISTINCT Nome_Produto FROM Tab_Dados_Escolha` is trivial, there's no reason to parameterize the column. Unless this *isn't* the real query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering the question that has been asked here, however, as I mentioned, this has the look and "smell" of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). As such, you should really be asking about the problem you are really trying to solve and that should (now) be in a new question.

As for what you've asked, as the comments have told you, you can't use a variable/parameter to replace column literal. Take something like the below:

```sql
DECLARE @ColName sysname;
SET @ColName = N'Nome_Produto';

SELECT DISTINCT @ColName
FROM dbo.Tab_Dados_Escolha;
```

This *won't* return a single row for each distinct value in the column `Nome_Produto`. instead it'll return a single row and column with the value `N'Nome_Produto'`. That's it. This is because the variable/parameter isn't interpreted to mean "return the value of the column with the value of the `@ColName`" but simply "return the value of `@ColName`".

As a result, you need to use dynamic SQL and **safely** inject the value. I also recommend validating the value passed so that if the column does not exist you don't run any (dynamic) SQL. This means you need to do something like this:

```sql
DECLARE @Colname sysname; --Your Parameter
SET @ColName = N'Nome_Produto'; --Parameter Value

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT DISTINCT ' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N' FROM dbo.Tab_Dados_Escolha;'
FROM sys.schemas s
     JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
     JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE s.[name] = N'dbo' --assumed
  AND t.[name] = N'Tab_Dados_Escolha'
  AND c.[name] = @Colname;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Of course, none of this touches on parametrisation for the dynamic SQL, etc, but that is also a very different question.

Use of dynamic SQL, however, is really not recommended unless you really know what you're doing with it. If you don't understand even something this simple, don't use it. Instead, rethink your design, as it's likely flawed.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have a large database and I am trying to develop an application that queries this database, and a query that was requested is to show a list of all the names in the determinate column in the database, without repetition, and I chose on going this way, thank you

Comment: Why does that therefore need a dynamic query though, @VitorMarquesLourenço ... It doesn't.

Comment: I am looking to expand this code to all the columns of this table in the database, and to other tables too, that way I use only one code and make it possible to query other tables as well, replacing the external variable @ColName with the name of the column selected by the mouse , thank you for your help!